# Asking about reducing sentence

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

I have a reduced sentence:

> "The line graph compares the amount of electricity produced in France using four different sources of power over a period of 32 years."

I think the full sentence is:

> "The line graph compares the amount of electricity **which is produced** in France **that uses four** different sources of power over a period of 32 years."

So there are 2 relative clauses in this sentence, as I know, a correct sentence has just a relative clause. so please help me understand this.

Comment: "using" is not quite the same as "that uses".  Sometimes it's more or less interchangeable, as in "the program using the file" = "the program that uses the file", but when it's part of an adverbial phrase, it's not the same.  "Electricity is produced using oil" is correct, but "electricity is produced that uses oil" doesn't sound right.

Comment: Personally, I would replace "using" with "by." (AmEng native speaker)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong having two relative clauses.

When a participle is used, they replace the verb in any tense. (Past, present, or future.) For instance,

> 1. *First prize is for the most points **which were scored/are scored/will be scored** in the game.
>
>      → First prize is for the most points **scored** in the game.*
> 2. *The winner is the person **who scored/scores/will score** the most points in the game.
>
>      → The winner is the person **scoring** the post points in the game.*

Comment: the word "using" is not follow to be. So can you explain for me the case of this "...produced in France using four different sources of power over a period of 32 years.

Comment: @ThanhBinh See stangdon's comment below your question.